# How to add a new list of information to Firebase’s firestore so all users can see it the next time they open the app?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm building an iOS app with Swift that currently uses Firebase.

Here is what I want to do:

I have a list of items, whenever I add or subtract items from that list I want to send the updated list to all users, they will receive the updated list the next time they open the app.

How should I approach this? Is it possible with Firebase?

Comment: you cannot send large list via FCM due to size limitation https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages, instead read the values everytime you open the app as kevin suggested

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @ked how could I add the new list to firestore so all users can see it the next time they open the app?

Comment: This invloves very broad explanation, check firestore documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore and for adding new list you can build an app if that's convienient for you, you can also store data using admin SDK like NodeJs or python

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue
I solved it by making the users download the list each time the user enters the app.
the issue here is that they must be connected to the internet
you can back it up and check: if internet is offline - use the old list in your local database

Comment: Hi Kevin! Thanks! Where could I as an admin place my list if i was to use Firebase?

Comment: You can either use realtime database or firestore to save your list

Comment: @ked if I put it in realtime database or firestore would all my users have access to that list? How could I put it in either of those?

Comment: do want to give read access to all the users?

Comment: @ked yes, I do.